# Let $(e_n)$ be ONB for $H$. Define $T_n \in B(H)$ as $T_n(x)= \langle x,e_n\rangle e_1$. Show that $T_n$ converges strongly but in Norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I was looking for a example for sequence of bounded operators which converges strongly but does not converge in Norm. I've found the following example somewhere on internet, but unable to prove this.

> Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $(e_n)$ be ONB for $H$. Define $T_n \in B(H)$ as $T_n(x)= \langle x,e_n\rangle e_1$ Show that $T_n$ converges strongly but not in Norm.

I think $T_n$ converges to zero strongly. Is this correct? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $T_n$ converges strongly to zero by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma: For any $x\in H$,
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \langle x,e_n\rangle = 0
$$
which itself follows from Bessel's inequality
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\langle x,e_n\rangle | ^2 \leq \|x\|^2
$$

Furthermore, $T_n$ does not converge in norm, because if $n\neq m$
$$
\|T_n - T_m\| \geq \|T_n(e_n) - T_m(e_m)\| = \|e_1\| = 1
$$